# How can I prevent javascript code theft?

Tags: php, javascript

Actually I'm developing a Chrome extension and a jQuery plugin to upload it and sell it on Codecanyon. When I "Inspect source" of the page and I click on the "Resources" tab, the javascript file looks empty. How does Codecanyon do that? I want to have file theft prevention in my own website too, but I don't know how to do it. I know php and javascript and there's no method to do it, because the browser downloads the file to execute it.

You can see the example [here](http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/circular_countdown_cc/).

Comment: The file is empty because the actual countdown JS code is in `jquery.js`. You can not hide it as long as it's client side.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software) - http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/JavaScript/Tools/Obfuscators/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only try to make it less readable (through minifiaction and obfuscation), but the code is still tranferred and it can be reverse engineered.

The actual code in your example is downloaded with the jquery.js file.

Answer (score 35):

You cannot hide it because your browser needs it to perform it. Simple as that.

You need to understand that it is a script executed on the client side. It is not compiled (meaning it's not a binary (0 and 1 machine language)). So it is freely readable.

Nevertheless you can obfuscate it using tools like [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/)

Basically this kind of tools remove extra spacing, tabs line returns and rename methods (like method "a" standing for "MyShinyMethodWhoMakesNiceStuff") and variables. That makes it very difficult to read and understand code. Reverse engineering is thus harder to achieve.

Some uses some tricks like base64 or other encode and decode part of code with a function but it's only tricks and will not fool the sharp eye.

By obfuscation, you make people spend much more time in analyzing your code and stealing is thus much more complex, and takes time. Let's say you made a nice javascript plugin that makes every white background in purple (ok, not so great example but used it just for having an imaged example). Somebody might want to steal it and makes it blue instead of purple. If code is obfuscated, he might think that's easier to copy your idea and rewrites it on his own with his own code and blue background, it will takes him less time than reverse engineers and understanding wells yours, easier to maintain in the time too. In the end he will "only" "steal" your idea but not your code.

I think that in the end, it's just a matter of time.

Comment: But with each one of these tools, the code can be reversed (even if it is hardly readable).

Comment: @Arthur : of course. The only way is to discourage people from trying to unobfuscate it. I will precise it in my post.

Comment: It would be cool if they had one of thease applications that would RANDOMLY generate names/variables.

Comment: @Annonous: That's one of the things the obfuscation tools do.

Comment: This is the same conceptual flaw that DRM has: you must have the copyrighted material, and a reader/player, in order to consume it. Since there can be no real technical barrier, DRM advocates try to use the law to keep you from having a reader/player you control. But it's unlikely we'll ever have browsers that won't show us the Javascript they're executing (and it would kill JS innovation if we did).

Comment: Good obfuscators make code almost completely unrecoverable to the point that it is just not worth it.

Comment: @Andrey: it's not worth it, because it's not worth stealing in the first place -- do something absolutely unique and valuable, and they will find it worth recovering. moxy's example of changing purple to blue is actually  a great example -- someone might want to steal that, and be put off by mangled names and what not, write their own. Do something worth a few hundred thousand or more and it will be a different story.

Comment: @jmoreno unfortunately it is usually worth stealing, so make your stuff either opensource or protect it well.

Comment: @loops: what's your question?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, just curious how samy did a No source for you! when we click view source.

Comment: @loops: that's an old trick.. have you ever took a look at the scroll bar?

Answer (score 13):

If you see it's empty, it means that it's empty. There is no way to hide your javascript code from a client that must execute the code.

Answer (score 2):

On JavaScript "protection" - basically what everyone else said.

Explaining the [example you provided](http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/circular_countdown_cc/):

Indeed, http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/circular_countdown_cc/js/countdown.min.js appears to be empty, however the actual plugin code is appended to the jquery.js file, starting at line 58:

http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/circular_countdown_cc/js/jquery.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **javascript obfuscator tools:**

[http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/)
http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're licensing the code on a per-site basis, I would suggest domain locking your javascript as well.

You can do this yourself by simply checking the window.location somewhere in an encrypted file. This isn't going to be very secure, but for 90% of users who just drop a script into a directory and hope it works, it will provide some level of deterrent.

You can also use https://domainlockjs.com (free) to easily lock scripts to domains. This is a slightly better solution because DomainLockJS throws hard to trace errors and is much harder to debug.

A more complicated approach would involve using an Ajax script injection, and allowing specific domains to access the script / not trigger an XSS error. This is the hardest to set up, but if you inject a large amount of js, it might be the hardest to get around.

All of these can be circumvented by a skilled coder though... you're only making things difficult, not impossible.

Answer (score -8):

Liblock is a small tool built by myself. It encrypts your JS-sources - it's no simple obscurity by obfuscation, but good security by encryption.

When you inspect the DOM in your client, all you'll see is: nplreq(url) for each script that you bind into HTML head.

See how it works here [liblock-demo](http://ec2-176-34-64-10.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/nopro/xscroll) - this is a demo only for hiding the scripts in "nopro_lib" and "xscroll.js".

Encryption and decryption are totally transparent to the browser. It is tested with Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Konqueror, IE8-10  on PC, and with Dolphin and Safari on an Android tablet.

The sources are securely hidden, and only with really great efforts they may be layed open again. Encryption is done with AES (Rijndael 256) using one-shot-keys which are negotiated between client and (liblock-)server using Diffie-Hellman.

Comment: "good security by encryption" - that's BS. If the browser can decrypt it everyone else can do so, too. So it's actually *worse* than obfuscation.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It looks like typing `$('script')` in the console is enough to break the security here.